# transferring raw schematic to breadboard and PCB

Tags: pcb, schematics, breadboard

i have some schematic from TINA pro, pspice, orcad and the lite. Is there a way to automatically convert it into a both breadboard and PCB layout. This is a bright idea since it will save time. What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use TINA pro, then let say you have a circuit below

a very simple circuit indeed :))

[image]

and follow below

[image]

and there, you have it

[image]